# SQL Server 2008 R2 uninstallation error - The path cannot be found

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to uninstall SQL Server 2008 R2 from my machine, but I get this error:

[image]

Any help please?

Comment: This seems a bit off topic as its not directly programming related

Answer (score 0):

The uninstaller needs the msisupport.msi to uninstall.

Insert the installation CD and browse to the location displayed (the CD should have a similar path).